# hydrate in the form of current tense

Tags: verbs

would the phrase "i'm hydrating" make sense? because the word hydrate in definition means: cause to absorb or combine with water. so is it actually correct usage of the word when said the phrase "i'm hydrating"?

Comment: We use capital letters in appropriate places in English.  If you want to ask a question, please at least write it in English.  If you're learning English, you might find the English Language Learners site (http://ell.stackexchange.com/) more appropriate.   The simple answer to your question is that the term is not normally used in that manner, but you might talk about hydrating someone in a medical context.

Comment: It would not be that odd for a health nut, when asked what he was doing at the moment, to reply "I'm hydrating".  This would imply that he was engaged in drinking water or some sort of "sports drink".

Comment: *Hydrate* in ordinary speech means *drink sufficient water*

Comment: And of course a chemist might describe "hydrating" some chemical mix.

Comment: And "hydrating" is what a concrete guy does when he adds water to the mixture of cement, sand, and gravel.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would say that you are ***trying to stay hydrated***. This isn't to say you couldn't say you are *hydrating* yourself (it is a verb like any other), but it's much more often to hear the other construction.